# Wordpress 3.8.1 TinyMCE does not seem to be rendering my pages' <div> elements

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tinymce

I've created several pages in wp-admin and inserted the needed HTML. Each page contains multiple nested div elements. An example of one of my pages is the following Contact page:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="inner-content" class="row clearfix">
    <div id="main" class="large-12 medium-12 columns clearfix" role="main">
        <strong>Artist Name</strong>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a class="email" href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Email Artist</a>
        <h3 class="team-title">Artist's Team</h3>
        <ul class="team-list">
            <li>
                <strong>Sarah</strong><p class="team-role"> : Fine Art Agent</p>
                <p class="company">Some Agency, NYC</p>
                <a class="email" href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Email Sarah</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <strong>Justin</strong><p class="team-role"> : Manager</p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a class="email" href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Email Justin</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <strong>Jesse</strong><p class="team-role"> : Publicist</p>
                <p class="company">Another Art Agency</p>
                <a class="email" href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Email Jesse</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- end #main -->
</div> <!-- end #inner-content -->
```

For this Contact page I have chosen the Contact (contact.php) template for it in the Page Attributes > Template dropdown menu like so:

[image]

And the contents of the `contact.php` are:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Contact */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For some reason when I go to view the Contact page, all I see is the header and footer. All of the HTML code get's ignored by Wordpress. Why is this happening? And how to fix it?

Comment: Just to offer an alternative, consider using contact form 7 (WP plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well your `contact.php` is missing the post output, the minimal code should be something like that

```
<?php the_post(); the_content(); ?>
```

e.g. set the first post as current (skipping the loop) then output its content. though as you added plain html to the page content (often seen as a no-no) it maybe better to directly echo content like that:

```
<?php the_post(); global $post; echo $post->post_content; ?>
```

that way you skip wordpress filters that add paragraphs etc. to the content.